# How to set Default Values for fields in Realm?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, mobile, realm

How can we give a default to the realm model field?

Example :

```
class Demo extends RealmObject{
    private String id; // I want to set this id to a uuid 
    private boolean isVisibile; // set this to default as true              
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Demo extends RealmObject{
    public Demo() {
        id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        isVisible = true;
    } 

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id; // I want to set this id to a uuid 
    private boolean isVisibile; // set this to default as true              
}
```

Should work Realm 2.0+

Comment: Will i be able to use realm.createObject(Demo.class, UUID.randomUuid().toString()) in this case?

Comment: I think so, sure

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, will  realm.createObject(Demo.class, UUID.randomUuid().toString()) update the object if realm finds same entry? if not how can i update it? i am using Gson and getting Mapped object so i need to update Id after this mapping.

Comment: Well if you get a new instance with the same random UUID then I think that's called "super bad luck". But no, `createObject` throws exception if the class already exists, You can `findFirst()` it first to see if it exists.